# JAX-RPC remoting of enum

Tags: java, web-services, enums, jax-rpc

I wrote a function using an enum for filtering with this signature:

```
/**
 * Match a profile with other profiles meaning they are similar.
 * 
 * @param profileId
 *            the profile to match
 * @param actuality
 *            the actuality to use for filtering
 * @return a ordered list of the best matching profiles
 */
public Match[] match(String profileId, Actuality actuality)
```

The enum looks like this:

```
public enum Actuality {
    /** Only show data within 5 days. */
    BRAND_NEW,
    /** Show data within 45 days. */
    NEW,
    /** Show all data. */
    ALL,
}
```

Is it possible to remote Actuality enum with JAX-RPC? If you could suggest another nice way of doing this (Not just pass an int) with JAX-RPC would also be very helpful.

Comment: If you are writing the server side of the WS, I suggest to migrate to a newer stadanrd like JAX-WS. Anyway I think because that SOAP standard are always moving the SOAP should be replaced by lighter services like e.g JSON/REST.